# Formula for offsetting some additional percentage like an added fee

Tags: arithmetic

Say I want to pay someone `$100.00` but the service I use keeps 3% of the payment I make. Meaning they would only receive `$97.00` since they would keep `$3`. If I increase my payment to `$103` they would keep $3.09 meaning they would only receive `$99.91`. Is there a formula to calculate the exact extra amount I'd need to pay in order to offset the percentage fee?

(I know this is tagged incorrectly but I can't create tags yet and I didn't see any that fit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is the quantity you pay, then they keep $0.97x$. Since you want $0.97x$ to equal $100$, you have
\begin{align*}
0.97 x &= 100\\
x & = & \frac{100}{0.97}\\
x & \approx & 103.0928
\end{align*}
so you would want to give them something between `$`$103.09$ and `$`$103.10$ (as it happens, 97% of 103.09 is 99.9973, which would be rounded up to 100 by most, and 97% of 103.10 is 100.007, which would be rounded up to 100.01 by most).

In general, if you want them to get $T$ and they only get $r$% of what you give them, then the formula is that you want to give them $x$, where
$$x = \frac{100T}{r}.$$

Comment: Oh duh. I didn't think of it like that.

Answer (score 3):

You want to pay `x` to someone, but services take `r`%, you have to pay them `y`.

Since $\large x = y \cdot (1 - \frac r {100})$

Then $\large y = \frac x {1 - \frac r {100}}$

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to get 97% of x, and you want to get $100, then:

100 = .97x

(divide each side by .97)

100/.97 = x

Answer (score 1):

In general suppose $FV$ is the future value of an asset and $PV$ is the present value of an asset. Then $FV = \frac{PV}{(1-d)^n}$ where $d = i/(i+1)$ (where $i$ is the annual effective interest rate) is the discount rate. In this example, $d = 0.03$, $n=1$ and $FV = 100$.